# Retrieve Id of a React.js element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set a static id to react element and `onClick` listener is set to the component, I pass the event object as the param to the listener function and `event.target.id` is an empty `string`, how do I get the id of the clicked element?

If I didn't call `event.persist()`, I am getting all values null, why is it so?

```js
sendDisplayType = (event) => {
  event.persist();
  console.log(event);
}
```

```html
<div id="mission" onClick={this.sendDisplayType} className="col l8 m6 left-align nopaddingleft white-space greentext">
    <h5> <b>Our Mission</b></h5>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a [mcve]? It is firing on the `<b>` tag.

Comment: Why did you set a static id?  Why did you not use _refs_?

Answer (score 0):

the event generated is not `dom event`, it is `react event`, you should set `ref` on the `div` tag to get access to its values including id.

Answer (score 0):

> If I didn't call event.persist(), I am getting all values null, why is it so?

All properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons.[Reference for event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

To get an id, what I usually do is just do a classic `document.getElementById('id')`.

But if you really want to go the event way without calling a function on the event prop, what you can do is pass the id as `data`

so:

```
<div id="mission" data-id="mission" onClick={this.sendDisplayType} className="col l8 m6 left-align nopaddingleft white-space greentext">
    <h5> <b>Our Mission</b></h5>
</div>
```

Then get it as:

```
sendDisplayType = (event) => {
  event.persist();
  console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
}
```

**I strongly recommend the code above** compare on adding an arrow function like:

```
  <div id="mission" onClick={() => this.sendDisplayType('mission')} />
```

I don't usually use the code above (calling a function on prop) because of optimization (so if you have a performance issue, optimize as much as possible) - [React docs explaining this](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render)